# Android cannot send mail

Tags: email, stock-email-app

After working fine for a while, since a couple of months our tablet **cannot send** mails from mail accounts across several providers. However, *receiving* mails works. I tried whatever I could think of or found on the internet (see below), and I am quite desperate...
This page shows several possibly related questions, but they do not describe my problem.

It says "sending ..." -> **Error message** "senden fehlgeschlagen" = sending did not work. Update: Sometimes (seems random, possibly because it is shown for short time ~ 1 sec) it also says in addition "Server nicht verfügbar" = server not accessible (although internet and smtp server work when tested from the other devices, see below).

**Device:**

- Samsung Galaxy 10, 2014 edition Android 5.1.1, Safety patch 2017-04-01
  (i.e. all regular updates offered for it)
- has enough memory > 6 GB free
- mail client: standard Android mail client
- mails are managed via **IMAP** (not POP3) / **SMTP**

**Mail providers tested:**

- web.de (2 accounts from 2 people)
- mail.de
- tested each time with only one single account set (and all others removed), just to make absolutely sure the do not interfere with each other

**What DOES work is the following:**

- sending (and every else) mails from each of the accounts using a) another android device (Samsung Galaxy phone, Android 5.0.1 - i.e. all regular updates offered for that device), b) PC/Thunderbird, and c) webmail.
- send & receive mails via POP3. I wish to use IMAP (PORT numbers adjusted, same settings exp. for outgoing (SMTP) server).
- internet bandwidth (45 MBit/s download, 6 Mbit upload, ping 92 ms) and volume

**What I tried so far, without success:**

- shut down and restart the device
- double-check  mail account settings (incoming: imap.web.de / imap.mail.de, SSL, port 993, optional imap path prefix: none; outgoing: smtp.web.de / smtp.mail.de, TLS, port 587, "Anmeldung erfordern" = need authentification checked in checkbox, same PW). All is set as suggested by the respective providers, and as set in the other android device from which I can send mails.Tried also alternative settings (e.g. SMTP: port 25, and other settings), but this did not improve anything (even though probably not all possible combinations)
- Removed and re-created the accounts (only one at a time). Still can receive, but not send.
- Tried another WiFi at a friend's home, different telecommunication
  provider, same problem. There is no problem with bandwith, internet volume etc.
- Tried on multiple days since several weeks to months
- Mail app is updated
- I prefer the normal android client. To our knowledge, there is no other (possibly interfering) client installed.
- UPDATES:
- As suggested in comment below (thanks!): deleted all data and 
  deleted all cache from mail app (and again deleted and re-created
  account) - no change.
- No certificates are needed, but the mail provider requests the users to specifically allow mail clients (mail clients/apps in general, i.e. management via IMAP/POP3, as opposed to the provider's web surface). This option has always been and is still chosen (doublechecked, and works from other devices).

Thanks in advance, I am looking forward to your help.

Comment: Try clearing data for the mail app. Settings>apps>mail>storage>clear data. This will delete all the data that's saved in the app. But any data that's already in the cloud is not going to be deleted

Comment: @Abochur: Thanks, hope I got this right, menu seems a little bit different. Went to settings > apps > E-Mail: delete all app data, and delete all app cache. Unfortunately id not help. Updates list in my question to keep anoverview.

Comment: @beeshyams: sorry - what do you mean by "chat the cache"? I cleared the cache, without improvement.

Comment: +1, good point - my work mail does, but not these free mail providers used on the tablet. Updates list in question accordingly to keep track...

Comment: I've also recently had email behave really oddly. Early December, out of nowhere it suddenly ate up 4 GB of my mobile data limit (which was 3GB), and it seems that things I emailed since then never arrived or arrived weeks late. I also found an email from last summer in my outbox.

Honestly, this behaviour is so bizarre and broken that I'm inclined to consider the app broken en look for a better one.